# Split a string at the words AND and OR, keeping the separators

Tags: python, list, split

I want to split the following string

```
string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 OR variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'"
```

at the AND and OR position, so that I can return the following list

```
list = ["events.error > 5", "AND", "timeseries.temperature < 20", "OR", "variants.battery = 'Li'", "AND", "vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```

I tried string.split() but the groups are also split by the spaces. Do you know a better approach ?

Comment: `import re` with `re.split(r' (AND|OR) ', string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `re.split`, putting the separator in a group will make it be kept in the output:

```
import re

string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 AND variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'"

re.split(r'(AND)', string)
```

Output:

```
['events.error > 5 ',
 'AND',
 ' timeseries.temperature < 20 ',
 'AND',
 " variants.battery = 'Li' ",
 'AND',
 " vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```

---

Edit: as you included a second separator 'OR', the updated version:

```
import re

string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 OR variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'"

re.split(r'(AND|OR)', string)
```

Output:

```
['events.error > 5 ',
 'AND',
 ' timeseries.temperature < 20 ',
 'OR',
 " variants.battery = 'Li' ",
 'AND',
 " vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```

If you want to get rid of the spaces around your strings, you can include any number of leading and trailing spaces in the separator, but outside of the group, so that they don't appear in the output:

```
import re

string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 OR variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'"

re.split(r'\s*(AND|OR)\s*', string)  # include the spaces in the separator, 
                                     # but don't keep them
```

Output:

```
['events.error > 5',
 'AND',
 'timeseries.temperature < 20',
 'OR',
 "variants.battery = 'Li'",
 'AND',
 "vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```

Comment: `r' (AND) '` gets rid of those leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could `split()` the string on `"AND"`, then intersperse `"AND` between the items in the list. It also seems you don't want any trailing whitespace, so you need to `strip()` that as well.

```
string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 AND variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'"

def intersperse(lst, item):
    result = [item] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)
    result[0::2] = lst
    return result

result = intersperse([x.strip() for x in string.split("AND")], "AND")

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['events.error > 5', 'AND', 'timeseries.temperature < 20', 'AND', "variants.battery = 'Li'", 'AND', "vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by a string with `string.split("AND")`, and then `.strip()` to lost the leading/trailing whitespaces:

```
my_string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 AND variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'" 
my_list = my_string.split('AND') 
my_list = [x.strip() for x in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

returns

```
['events.error > 5', 'timeseries.temperature < 20', "variants.battery = 'Li'", "vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```

Note that without the `.strip()`, you keep needless whitespaces, which you probably don't want.

Comment: The OP wants to keep AND

Comment: You're right! Missed that.

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot something. It's at the AND/OR position. I also want to keep the AND and OR in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `split()` with `itertools.cycle()` and `zip()`:

```
import itertools


string = "events.error > 5 AND timeseries.temperature < 20 AND variants.battery = 'Li' AND vehicle.name = 'Audi'"
print([x for y in zip(string.split(' AND '), itertools.cycle(['AND'])) for x in y][:-1])
# ['events.error > 5', 'AND', 'timeseries.temperature < 20', 'AND', "variants.battery = 'Li'", 'AND', "vehicle.name = 'Audi'"]
```